# Python Removing AM and PM from column date

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Hello I tried different code to remove AM/MP from csv file in python (pandas).

```
 date_time
```

5/5/2014  7:42:39 AM

I used following code but UNFORTUNATELY nothing changes. Could you please let me know how can I get ride of PM/AM from column date in pandas?

```
df['TimeStamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TimeStamp'], format="%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")
```

Colud you please let me know what shall I do to remove them from column date?

Comment: what is the relation of the variable `date_time` to the dataframe's column `df['TimeStamp']`? Which format are you trying to change? What are the steps you take to change the format?

Comment: Yes it is df['TimeStamp'], I am trying to change the format to 5/5/2014 7:42:39 without am/pm, i try to change the format as soon as reading it using pandas.read_csv

Comment: you should be able to parse TimeStamp to datetime directly when loading the csv, e.g. like `pd.read_csv(filepath, parse_dates=['TimeStamp'])`. then format to string again with desired format and save as csv. @MalayParmar shows this in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try if this works:

```
df['TimeStamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TimeStamp'], format="%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")
df['TimeStamp'] = df['TimeStamp'].dt.strftime("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
```

Comment: I test with %p and without it, there is no difference.

Comment: Did you save it to the file after you ran this code?

Comment: Yes I did it in the csv file, and import it in excel using tab "Data", the column includes AM and PM. Unfortunately, I got stuck, my code doesn't perform because of this issue.

Comment: @AsaYa I modified the answer once again, try it out

Comment: it returns  this error "Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values"

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I just noticed you were using double quotes here `"%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p"`
try using single quotes

```py
df['TimeStamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TimeStamp'], format='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
```

It might be because the column is coming in as a string. If it is, you could try removing the last three strings (AM/PM and the space before it) and then convert to date and time:

```py
df['TimeStamp'] = df['TimeStamp'].str[:-3]
df['TimeStamp']= pd.to_datetime(df['TimeStamp'])
```

Check the data type first though:

```py
print(df['TimeStamp'].dtypes)
```

Comment: performing your code returns this error " Can only use .str accessor with string values!"

Comment: Did you check the data type of the column? If so what data type did it say it was?

Comment: Yes I did, it is datetime

Comment: I just noticed something you are using double quotes here "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p" try using single quotes df['TimeStamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TimeStamp'], format='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers and comments. None of them cannot remove AM/PM, I just changed time format in control panel!!!!! it done!!!